# void* type to char* type leadng

Tags: c

The man has the code

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void dbleInt(void *a) {
    *((int*) a) *= 2;
}

void deleteEvenInt(void* a) {
    int tmp = *((int*) a);
    if (tmp % 2 == 0) {
        *((int*) a) = 0;
    }
}

void dbleDouble(void *a) {
    *((double*) a) *= 2.0;
}

void deleteEvenDouble(void* a) {
    int tmp = *((double*) a);
    if (tmp % 2 == 0) {
        *((double*) a) = 0;
    }
}

// Function takes an array, its size, the size of one element and a function //pointer,
// Which is then applied to all the elements of an array
void map(void *arr, unsigned num, size_t size, void (*fun)(void *)) {
    unsigned i;
    char *ptr = (char*) arr;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        fun((void*) (ptr + i*size));
    }
}
```

Why does he leads void* type to char* type? I can see thats it an error, when I change this code and dont lead it, but why?

Comment: Pointer arithmetic to `void*` type is determined by it's invalid standard.(Since the size of the `void` type (E.g. `sizeof(void)`) has not been determined) It is an extension to allow it in gcc. (Extension is set to 1 the size of the `void`)

Comment: "The man has the code" - sorry but No One can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allowed to perform arithmetic on void pointers in C. So the following code is illegal:

```
void *foo = whatever;
foo + 1;
```

By casting `foo` to a `char *`, she can perform arithmetic on the pointer.

Comment: In order to NOT violate strict aliasing, the caller would have to ensure the right type is passed to each function,,, For example, `double x=3.0; dbleInt(&x);` would be a violation of strict aliasing, right?

Answer (score 0):

My comments are on why `void *ptr`, one cannot perform address arithmetic.  Warning , Long rambling :).

In general
when you do  a ptr arithmetic like

```
ptr  = ptr + N ;
```

The interpretation by  C is to perform the following equivalent integer arithmetic  (Infact the compiler will  produce assembly code equivalent to below integer arithmetic)

**ptr = ptr + N* sizeof (typeof(*N)) ;**

Hence  The compiler has to know the typeof (*N) for it to produce code. typeof (*N) here means, the type of variable "ptr" points to. (typeof is not a standard c construct, it is being bought here for mere explanation).

Take an e.g.

```
int x ;  // Assume x is at addesss 1000
int *ptr =  &x ; // ptr has a value of 1000
```

Then 
ptr = ptr + 1 ;
would make ptr as 1004 during run time (assuming size of int is 4 bytes)

Explanation-1: The above statement means that ptr should  contain the address of next integer variable after ptr.  Since ptr  points to x , which is at address 1000, the next integer variable after 1000 would be 1004. So ptr would be 1004.

Explanation-2 This is also in sync with the interpretation of  ptr = ptr +N is equivalent  to  integer arithmeitc

```
ptr = ptr + N* sizeof (typeof(*N)) ; // typeof (*N)->int
           //  => 1000 + 1 *sizeof (typeof (int))
                               //  => 1004
```

To summarize For the ptr arith operation

```
ptr = ptr  + N ;
```

the compiler produces an equivalent assembly code as

ptr = ptr + N* sizeof (typeof(*N)) // Compiler Needs to typeof(*N)

**Hence the compiler needs to know what is the  data-type that ptr is pointing to**.

Now consider

```
void foo (int type, void *ptr) {

    ptr = ptr + 2 ;
}
f2() {
int x ;
char c ;
f1(&x) ;
f1(&c);
}
```

The void * ptr is a generic ptr pointing to an addresss.  When called with f1(&x) the ptr points to an address of integer, when called with f1(&c) it points to address of a character. So at compile time , compiler cannot determine what is the typeof  (*ptr). (for in one case it is integer and another is character).   Hence it is not possible for the compiler to generate code for
    ptr = ptr + n ;

So you will have to cast the ptr of being a particular known type and then do arithmetic operation.

Hope this helps.